# Collections of varying types used in implicit parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a function f(in:C*) that takes a varargs list of type C. I'd like to be able to provide implicits for A=>C and B=>C and then be able to call f() with a mixture of As and Bs:

```
object ImplicitSeq {  
case class A
case class B
case class C
implicit def a2c(a:A) : C = C()
implicit def b2c(b:B) : C = C()
def on_c[T<%C](in:T) = with_c(in)
def on_seq[T<%C](s:T*) = s map {with_c(_)}
def with_c(in:C) = println("Got C")

on_c(A())
on_seq(A(),A()) //Fine
on_seq(B(),B()) //Fine
on_seq(A(),B()) //Fails to compile
}
```

This hinges on [T <% C] meaning "a type T which can be converted to C" so that

```
def on_c[ T <% C](in:T)
```

becomes
    def on_cT(implicit ev:T=>C)

That works fine for individual objects, as T can be different each time it is called. But in sequences,
Seq(A(),B()) would have type Seq[AnyRef], which doesn't work.

I'd like to know if there is an elegant workaround? Something equivalent to saying Seq[_ <% C], meaning "A Seq of things which can be turned into Cs given the available implicits"?

Comment: View bounds are useful when you want the compiler to know about the pre-conversion type. That's not going to be possible in this case (and it doesn't seem like you care), so you can just use e.g. `def on_seq(in: C*)`.

Comment: (But you should avoid implicit conversions if you can.)

Comment: @TravisBrown does your last advice refer to this particular case or in general? and if so why should we avoid it?

Comment: Of course - `def on_seq(in:C*)` works. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Type classes or implicit classes are almost always better. In this case a type class-based approach would be a little tricky for the same reasons the view bound is, but there's likely a better solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to implicit classes - that does seem like a better way to go.